# Make bootstrap carousel responsive on height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I need to customize BS carousel, to make images size responsive corectly.
I need the carousel to adapt to the height of the active slides images initiel height.
When the viewport is wider than the image, the image/slide should scale up, but keep ratio.
When viewport is smaller the image should scale down but keep ratio.

I have tried many variations but cannot find the right solution.

I hope some css/js expert can help me out here.

Here's my current markup:

```
<!-- Carousel
================================================== -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="true">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active"><!--data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#777:#7a7a7a/text:First slide"-->
          <img src="MediaContent/Images/Unika%20kobbertryk%201.jpg" alt="First slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Example headline.</h1>
              <p>Note: If you're viewing this page via a <code>file://</code> URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item"> <!--data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#666:#6a6a6a/text:Second slide" -->
          <img src="MediaContent/Images/Unika%20kobbertryk%202.jpg" alt="Second slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
              <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item"><!--data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#555:#5a5a5a/text:Third slide"-->
          <img src="MediaContent/Images/Unika%20kobbertryk%203.jpg"  alt="Third slide">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
              <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
    </div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

And heres my currently css, that does not function like desciped. This version gives me a fixed 500px height, and an image that looses aspect ratio when viewport is smaller than image width.

```
/* GLOBAL STYLES

body {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
}


/* CUSTOMIZE THE NAVBAR
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Special class on .container surrounding .navbar, used for positioning it into place. */
.navbar-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 20;
}

/* Flip around the padding for proper display in narrow viewports */
.navbar-wrapper .container {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.navbar-wrapper .navbar {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}


/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  min-height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
  min-height: 500px;
  background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
}



/* MARKETING CONTENT
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Pad the edges of the mobile views a bit */
.marketing {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

/* Center align the text within the three columns below the carousel */
.marketing .col-lg-4 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.marketing h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.marketing .col-lg-4 p {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}


/* Featurettes
------------------------- */

.featurette-divider {
  margin: 80px 0; /* Space out the Bootstrap <hr> more */
}

/* Thin out the marketing headings */
.featurette-heading {
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}



/* RESPONSIVE CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */

@media (min-width: 768px) {

  /* Remove the edge padding needed for mobile */
  .marketing {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }

  /* Navbar positioning foo */
  .navbar-wrapper {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-wrapper .container {
    padding-left:  15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
  }
  .navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    padding-left:  0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }

  /* The navbar becomes detached from the top, so we round the corners */
  .navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    border-radius: 4px;
  }

  /* Bump up size of carousel content */
  .carousel-caption p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 21px;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }

  .featurette-heading {
    font-size: 50px;
  }

}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .featurette-heading {
    margin-top: 120px;
  }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

In the CSS selector `.carousel-inner > .item > img`, replace `min-width` with `width: 100%;`

```css
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This works! In my bootstrap.css the default for that selector is `max-width: 100%`. If I change it to `width:100%` all the images are "stretched" to fill the viewport width.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it adding a class to the images in the carousel, for example :

```
<img class="fixed-height">
```

and in the css:

```
.fixed-height {
    max-height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I will refer you just to add the class "img-responsive" in the image tags. And Bootstrap will do the rest for you.

This class tells the Bootstrap that you want to scale the images according to the screen size.

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="theCarousel" data-interval="3000">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#theCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="http://www.ansupalake.in/gallery/tapan%20kumar%201.JPG" alt="1" class="img-responsive" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                         <h4 class="text-left">Resting In Style</h4>

                        <p class="text-left">Hi Everybody what's going on.....</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item ">
                    <img src="http://www.ansupalake.in/gallery/tapan%20kumar%202.JPG" alt="2" class="img-responsive" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                         <h4 class="text-left">The Dude Look</h4>

                        <p class="text-left">Hi Everybody what's going on.....</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item ">
                    <img src="http://www.ansupalake.in/gallery/tapan%20kumar.JPG" alt="3" class="img-responsive" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                         <h4 class="text-left">How z It??</h4>

                        <p class="text-left">Hi Everybody what's going on.....</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
```

For more details Here I have an article regrading this, You can take a look if you want

[Carousel Image Slider In Bootstrap 3](http://www.icodefor.net/2014/01/carousel-image-slider-in-twitter.html)

Comment: I don't think that this is the correct answer, at least in the current Bootstrap 3. In my bootstrap.css `img-responsive` and `.carousel-inner > .item > img` share the same rules. The OP is placing the images in .carousel-inner>.item so it should be enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem as above. Here's my solution. I changed a few lines of CSS:

```
.carousel {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
  min-width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

define for every devices such as

```
@media (min-width: 360px) {
  .carousel {
    min-height: 140px;
   margin-bottom: 60px;
  }
  /* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
  .carousel-caption {
    z-index: 10;
    }

   /* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
   .carousel .item {
    min-height: 140px;
    background-color: #777;
    }
   .carousel-inner > .item > img {
    position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   min-width: 100%;
   min-height: 140px;
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

To use images on Bootstrap carousel of different sizes and to do the followings, all at the same time,

1. Image's width on carousael = 100%
2. Carousel image slide height = fixed
3. Maintain the image ratio

Remove the ***img*** tag & add a new class instead, say ***slide1***

```
<div class="item slide1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h1>Slide1 headline.</h1>
      <p>Slide content.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

then add the following CSS code for ***slide1*** class,

```
.slide1{
    height: 500px;  /* your desired height for this slide */
    background: url(/img/your-img.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

You may also configure this heights for different window sizes.

Comment: this won't adapt to the viewport as the OP asks because you're setting a fixed height

Comment: yap only height* should be configured manually for different sizes as i mentioned before. but the contents inside it will adopt viewport & images will also maintain ratio

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem adding the class "img-responsive" in the image tags made images responsive

```
            <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="/imahes/my-image.jpg" alt="1" class="img-responsive" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                     <h4 class="text-left">My caption</h4>

                </div>
            </div>
```

but the problem was with the slider height so I need to add a media query to resize the control div

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
.carousel-control{
  height:350px;
}
}
```

this media query is just an example, customize it to suit your needs, I hope that will help