# Bug (?) on Bootstrap 3 Carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I have used bootstrap 3 carousel and the images inside it were not getting resized accordingly.

After making this chage:

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

As shown in:
[Make bootstrap carousel responsive on height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849539/make-bootstrap-carousel-responsive-on-height)

It worked perfectly.

Would it be a bug or after making this change I will suffer some side effect?

Answer (score 3):

This is not a "BUG".

Bootstrap carousel doesn't handle correctly pictures that have not the same size.

[Here](http://parkhurstdesign.com/improved-carousels-twitter-bootstrap/) is a good tutorial that give a solution to the problem.